# how to invoke a webservice from one container in another container in glassfish

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, jax-ws

I have webservices deployed on two containers in two separate servers A and B.
A webMethod in 'Server A' needs to invoke a webmethod in 'Server B'.

I have created a client stub for Sever B. Im trying to make 'Server A' use this client stub and talk to Server B. I get an exception while trying to instantiate the port object
specifically at : service.getABCBeanPort();

(using JAX-WS library)

Is my approach correct? Is there any better way of invoking a webservice on a remote server?

This is my sample code 

 `public void autoPostRoomCharge() {
   
     try {
   
         BedHistoryManagerBeanService bs = new BedHistoryManagerBeanService();
            BedHistoryManagerBean bb = bs.getBedHistoryManagerBeanPort(); //bombs here
    
          } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Exception:" + e.getMessage());
        }
      

    }`


Here is the exception stack trace


`at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:3794) at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:3596) at com.sun.ejb.containers.WebServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(WebServiceInvocationHandler.java:201) at $Proxy170.autoPostRoomCharges(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.InvokerImpl.invoke(InvokerImpl.java:78) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.EjbInvokerImpl.invoke(EjbInvokerImpl.java:82) at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:146) at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:257) at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:93) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:106) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:147) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:106) at com.sun.xml.ws.tx.service.TxServerPipe.process(TxServerPipe.java:317) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:222) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:133) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436) at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:243) at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:444) at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244) at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.handlePost(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:113) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.invoke(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:87) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.EjbWebServiceServlet.dispatchToEjbEndpoint(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:228) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:157) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) at com.sun.enterprise.web.AdHocContextValve.invoke(AdHocContextValve.java:114) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:87) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096) at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:288) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:647) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:579) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:831) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:265) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface com.sun.xml.ws.developer.WSBindingProvider is not visible from class loader at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass(Proxy.java:353) at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:581) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:591) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:329) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:311) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:304) at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:92) at com.kebok.ais.bedmanagement.ejb.BedHistoryManagerBeanService.getBedHistoryManagerBeanPort(BedHistoryManagerBeanService.java:56) at com.kebok.ais.billing.server.ejb.impl.ChargeManagerBean.autoPostRoomCharges(ChargeManagerBean.java:108) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at com.sun.enterprise.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1011) at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityUtil.invoke(SecurityUtil.java:175) at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeTargetBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:2920) at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4011) at com.sun.ejb.containers.WebServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(WebServiceInvocationHandler.java:190) ... 63 more`

Comment: Your approach is valid but providing the exception (and the trace) would help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Pascal is right... the info from the stack trace would be really valuable for diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach sounds correct.

You may want to read through this [tutorial about creating a web service client](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html) of a pre-deployed remote service.

One thing that may have happened is that you have created your client reference poorly...

I would:

1. develop the service (in project B, I
   think).
2. deploy the service (in project B)
   onto host B.
3. create the web service reference in
   project A to the service deployed on
   B, by using the wsdl that you
   retrieve from host B.  Do not create
   the web service reference by
   referencing project B from project
   A...

Comment: @vkraemer I have created a reference to B using the wsdl. There is no dependency between A and B otherwise. I am able to access the webservice using the tutorial. I need to adapt it to use EJB instead of servlets. I'll give it a try and tell how it goes.
Cheers

Comment: the solution for this question is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777147/how-can-i-invoke-a-webservice-from-another-webservice