# how can I invoke a webservice from another webservice

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.0, jax-ws

I have two webservices A and B. A needs to invoke one of the webMethods in B.
How can I achieve this?
I am using maven's wsimport plugin to build A. This is to generate the necessary stubs for B and include them as part of the Webservice A.
However, when I try to Invoke the webmethod o f B, I get an Exception. Can anyone please tell me what is going on?
Below Is the code and the exception trace:
Code:

```
BBeanService bbs = new BBeanService();
BBean bb = bbs.getBBeanPort();            
bb.invokeWebService(); // this is throwing exception
```

This is the exception trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:188) at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:116) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:118) at $Proxy175.getCase(Unknown Source) at com.kebok.ais.billing.server.ejb.impl.ChargeManagerBean.generateBillDetails(ChargeManagerBean.java:144) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at com.sun.enterprise.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1011) at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityUtil.invoke(SecurityUtil.java:175) at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeTargetBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:2920) at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4011) at com.sun.ejb.containers.WebServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(WebServiceInvocationHandler.java:190) at $Proxy173.generateBillDetails(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.InvokerImpl.invoke(InvokerImpl.java:78) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.EjbInvokerImpl.invoke(EjbInvokerImpl.java:82) at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:146) at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:257) at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:93) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:106) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:147) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:106) at com.sun.xml.ws.tx.service.TxServerPipe.process(TxServerPipe.java:317) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:222) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:133) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436) at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:243) at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:444) at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244) at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.handlePost(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:113) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.invoke(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:87) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.EjbWebServiceServlet.dispatchToEjbEndpoint(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:228) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:157) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) at com.sun.enterprise.web.AdHocContextValve.invoke(AdHocContextValve.java:114) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:87) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096) at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:288) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:647) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:579) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:831) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214) at com.sun.enterprise.web.portunif.PortUnificationPipeline$PUTask.doTask(PortUnificationPipeline.java:380) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:265) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106) Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.enterprise.security.jmac.config.PipeHelper.makeFaultResponse(PipeHelper.java:328) at com.sun.enterprise.security.jmac.config.PipeHelper.getFaultResponse(PipeHelper.java:366) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:227) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:133) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436) at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:243) at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:444) at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244) at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.handlePost(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:113) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.invoke(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:87) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.EjbWebServiceServlet.dispatchToEjbEndpoint(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:228) at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:157) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) at com.sun.enterprise.web.AdHocContextValve.invoke(AdHocContextValve.java:114) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648) at org.apache.catalina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it working. All I had to do was annonate the method I am calling (In this case invokeService() in WebService BB with "@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)" and it all works without a hitch. I am not quite sure the reason behind this. Anyone?

Comment: is this also the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695215/how-to-invoke-a-webservice-from-one-container-in-another-container-in-glassfish??

Comment: You should probably open another question for the query that you have embedded in this answer.

Comment: @vkraemer yea it is the answer for  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695215/how-to-invoke-a-webservice-from-one-container-in-another-container-in-glassfish
as well.

Answer (score 0):

Me too, I had got the same probleme but I have solved it like this:
**If you use NetBeans** :

1. Create a project : web --> webapplication --> etc
2. you should create a client of your web service that you want to call.
   The methode is : right click your project---> webservice client.
   You should give the url of your WSDL and Netbeans will parse this WSDL and create the client.
3. Create your second web service (the web service that will call the first one ) in the same package. Juste right click your project ---> webservice.
4. **This part is the most important for your probleme**
   Please create a simple standard Java class in your project but with another package name.
   Create a default constructor (optional but good)
   Outside your default constructor, create a function that you give the name TestService(this is a simple exemple of name)
   Inside your function, right click and choose : Insert code ---> call web service operation.
   If any think is OK, you must see the service coming from the other web service that you want call its operations.(This, because of the client that you had created in step 2)
   Choose the operation that you want to call.
5. In your webservice, you can now call your TestService operation as a standard Java operation (instanciate your class, call the operation using the "." notation)
6. That is the all you need.
   Please, keep me informing about your progress...
   If you have any other problem about this, we can share informations until you get success... ok?
   I think that the best way is to use Netbeans if you want to work with webservices.
   Courage and sorry for my english....
   I am a frensh speeker.

Comment: @diengsallah : Thanks for the response. Your method is creating a standalone webservice client. It will work as long as the client is run from netbeans/desktop but will not work once deployed on glassfish. I want a webservice (which is deployed in glassfish) call another webservice internally.

Comment: I am beginning to suspect this feature is not available in Glassfish or it may be a bug??